# Google Cloud Storage file access control list public-read-write is not working in app engine java

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-storage

I am uploading image to Google Cloud Storage bucket. I want to give all user READ permission. Can anyone tell what should I pass in setAcl().

I want to get that image with http://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET_NAME/IMAGE_NAME.jpg.

Answer (score 1):

`public-read-write` is not a valid predefined ACL for objects, since objects, unlike buckets, do not really have a write permission. You are looking for `public-read`.

Comment: If you go to this link [click here](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#extension) then you will see google has listed it in predefined ACL list.

Comment: `public-read-write` is indeed a predefined ACL. The problem is that `public-read-write` applies only to buckets. There is no "write" permission for objects, and so such an ACL is equivalent to public-read at best and meaningless at worst.

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding. Yes you are right there is no facility to edit object on Google Cloud storage. Thanks for your quick reply.